# Why is there a quote_address_id field in sales_flat_order_address table?

Tags: address, sales-order, ee-1.13.1.0

Just stumbled upon the `quote_address_id` property of `sales/order_address` entity (`sales_flat_order_address` table) which in my case is always `NULL`.

Well I wonder .. what is is for? My only guess it is used at the stage when order is not yet finalised but I failed to find a proof in the code. Another guess may be backward compatibility.

The existence of this property/column is not critical of course. Just a question of curiosity.

Comment: Also there is quote_id in sales_flat_order table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Magento v1.4 `quote_address_id` was an attribute of the order entity. It looks like it was moved to the flat format in 1.4 along with many other attributes but I can't see it being used anywhere meaningful. I'd say it's a legacy item that's no longer in use.